# Why does Copy-Item not copy the files that Get-ChildItem returns with the same parameters?

Tags: powershell

Given the following sample input directory:

```
(Get-ChildItem . -Recurse).Fullname
C:\tmp\dir1
C:\tmp\dir2
C:\tmp\target
C:\tmp\dir1\get
C:\tmp\dir1\leave
C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1
C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir2
C:\tmp\dir1\get\notthis.cmd
C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1\file1.bat
C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1\file1.txt
C:\tmp\dir1\leave\file1.txt
C:\tmp\dir2\get
C:\tmp\dir2\leave
C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir1
C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir2
C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir1\file2.txt
C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir2\file2.bat
C:\tmp\dir2\leave\file2.txt
```

The goal is to create the following structure:

```
C:\tmp\target
C:\tmp\target\file1.txt  # from the get directory
C:\tmp\target\file1.bat
C:\tmp\target\file2.txt  # from the get directory
C:\tmp\target\file2.bat
```

- Get the *txt and *bat files only
- from all directories named "get" and their subidrectories

`Get-ChildItem` with the parameters `-Include` and `-Recurse` lists the correct files:

```
(get-childitem -path "*\ge*\*" -Recurse -include *.txt,*.bat).FullName
C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1\file1.bat
C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1\file1.txt
C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir1\file2.txt
C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir2\file2.bat
```

However `Copy-Item` with the same parameters does not copy any file:

```
Copy-Item -path "*\ge*\*" -Recurse -include *.txt,*.bat -Destination .\target\ -WhatIf
```

If I leave out the `-Include` parameter the files are copied but obviously includes the files that should not be included as well:

```
Copy-Item -path "*\ge*\*"  -Destination .\target\ -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1 Destination: C:\tmp\target\subdir1".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir2 Destination: C:\tmp\target\subdir2".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir1\get\notthis.cmd Destination: C:\tmp\target\notthis.cmd".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir1 Destination: C:\tmp\target\subdir1".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir2 Destination: C:\tmp\target\subdir2".
```

The help text for the `-Include` parameter is identical for `Copy-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`:

```
    -Include <String[]>
        Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet includes in the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as `"
        .txt"`. Wildcard characters are permitted. The Include * parameter is effective only when the command includes the contents of an item, such as `C:\Windows*`, where the wildcard character specifies
        the contents of the `C:\Windows` directory.
```

So why do these 2 commands behave differently?

I know I can pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem` into `ForEach-Object` and use that to copy. I just want to try once more to wrap my head around the logic of PowerShell.

This is using PowerShell 5.1 in case that matters.

Thanks in advance

Update:

This alternative command based on FletcherF1's suggestion also works in this example:

```
Copy-Item -path "*\ge*\*\*.txt","*\ge*\*\*.bat" -Destination .\target\ -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1\file1.txt Destination: C:\tmp\target\file1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir1\file2.txt Destination: C:\tmp\target\file2.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir1\get\subdir1\file1.bat Destination: C:\tmp\target\file1.bat".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\tmp\dir2\get\subdir2\file2.bat Destination: C:\tmp\target\file2.bat".
```

However this version requires to specify the exact depth of the structure. The parameter `-Recurse` has no effect.

Note: as I mentioned I'm not looking for alternatives but an explanation as to why these seemingly identical parameters behave differently.

Comment: I think the include parameter is a bit finicky. I have the same problem when I try to use -Path with any sort of qualifier like '*/foldername/*' and -Include. I don't have the problem if I just run it with -Path '*/*' though. I would probably just go with the second approach.

Comment: change this "Copy-Item -path "*\ge*\*" -Recurse -include *.txt,*.bat -Destination .\target\ -WhatIf" to this "Copy-Item -path "*\ge*\\*.txt","*\ge*\\*.bat" -Destination .\target\ -WhatIf"

Comment: `Copy-Item` has [issues](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10458). Either stream a list of objects as you've done with `Get-ChildItem` or try to use `robocopy`.